# Defining the Squaring Function in $(\mathbb{Z}; 0, 1, +, -, |)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm trying to show that the map $x\mapsto x^2$ is 0-definable in the structure $(\mathbb{Z}; 0, 1, +, -, |)$ (group of integers with the divisibility relation). But I'm not sure how to proceed. Any helpful hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35988/can-multiplication-be-defined-in-terms-of-divisibility. I leave it to the duplication police to decide whether your question is a duplicate, but the key bits of the solution are there (you'll need to fiddle around a bit to cater for $\Bbb{Z}$ rather than $\Bbb{N})$.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing something, but it's very unclear to me how to define LCM in this structure

Comment: $LCM(i, j)$ is the number that is divisible by $i$ and divisible by $j$ and that divides every other number with the same property.

Comment: (of course, in $\mathbb{Z}$, this definition of $LCM(i,j)$ picks out two numbers, not just one)

Comment: @AlexKruckman: that's why I said in my first comment that you need to fiddle around a bit to get it to work for $\Bbb{Z}$.